# Python backend in firebase

Tags: firebase

I am setting up a project in Firebase.
It will use:

- Authentication, to authenticate users
- Hosting for main html/js functions
- Storage for app data files
- Database for a small db

What I am currently missing is the availablity of a backoffice space into which I need to run python scripts that will gather files to save into Storage area with a cronjob.

Is this currently possible in Firebase, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase doesn't have a generalized backend solution for running arbitrary code.  You can bring whatever backend you want that meets your needs.

If you want to stay in the Google ecosystem, look into using Cloud Functions to run python code that's triggered by events in your system.  You can configure Cloud Scheduler to trigger a function periodically.

The Firebase tools built around Cloud Functions don't support python, only nodejs.